# Any viewers for Azure service fabric related ETW logs (and stored in Azure table storage)?

Tags: logging, azure-service-fabric, azure-table-storage, azure-diagnostics

I can enable the Azure diagnostics while creating service fabric cluster. I can also create my custom event types (for semantic logging) and log all the necessary events (in my micro-services), which are captured by azure diagnostics and dumped into Azure table storage. Now the data is stored successfully.

1. How can the operations team look at these logs?
2. Are there any tools out for simple viewing and filtering based on the event types?
3. What is the best way to look at these logs
4. If I have to build a tool that can view this data, what is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. They can use external tools or view it in Visual Studio via Cloud Explorer or via Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.
2. There are no tools particularly for events viewing. However, it is not so hard to compose a simple query to filter recorders. So you need to use any other tool that will allow you to view data and perform queries on Azure Table Storage.
3. Best way is the simplest way. All you going to need is possibility to compose queries and filter results by parameters' values. That means that at best you need a solution that will allow you to filter any parameter of log record.
4. Almost any logs viewing solution is a string for a query to filter results, and do it quickly. Modern search solutions are not only full-text search engines, but utilities to parse any unstructured data and figure out all the parameters to filter by itself, without predefined scheme. It allows to store logs data from any source with any format and then effectively search in it. For examples you could look at Elasticsearch or Splunk.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [serilog](https://serilog.net/) and [seq](http://getseq.net) to do this for some time. You will need to create your own server running seq, but that is relatively simple to do.

Have a look at a couple of git projects I've created that may help.

The cluster monitor which watches the event source and publishes to a seq instance
https://github.com/sceneskope/service-fabric-cluster-monitor

Some nuget packages for configuring and setting up a serilog logger that sends data to seq.

https://github.com/sceneskope/service-fabric

I've found this works the best for me and I wanted to make it available for other people so you don't need to struggle with how to manage and diagnose problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try Message Analyser. its available on microsoft.com here:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226